# How to say I would join but cant give an exact time. Basically, things would be a bit unpremediated and would need to play it by the ear?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, business-language

How do I say that since I am caught up in things and I cannot predict how they would go, I would have to be improvising on a given schedule and everyone else should go ahead without me? I could be a surprise element of support but cannot predict the extent of how much of it would be there.

Comment: You're really trying to pack all of that information into a single word?

Comment: No. Sorry for the misleading tag. I will remove it. I am new to the site and have a learning curve ahead. Regarding the question: I am looking for a professional way to say it. I am sure this is something that everyone must have tried to convey at some point. But, at the same time, I don't want to sound garrulous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might offer their **provisional acceptance** of a meeting invitation, which would countenance the probability of your schedule not actually allowing your attendance in point of fact.

[Provisional](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provisional)

> serving for the time being : TEMPORARY

I am a bit stilted and overly formal in business settings, but I would probably word it something like this.

> Thank you for the invitation. I would be very glad to attend, but unfortunately my schedule is a bit touch and go at present. So I will only be able to **accept provisionally** for the moment. I will try to inform you at the earliest opportunity if it becomes clear that I either will or will not be able to make it, but for now please do feel free to start without me. My apologies for the inconvenience.